# Object structure in virtual inheritance

Tags: c++

consider the code below (C++):

```
public class A{

// some virtual functions.
}

public class B : virtual A{

// some virtual function
}
```

how many virtual tables an object of kind B has? and where they are allocated?

Comment: [Mandatory reading](http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html).

Comment: What's a `public class` supposed to be?

Comment: I suppose this is homework. What are your own thoughts on the question? Have you read about `virtual inheritance` (See Kerrek's comment), was there anything you did not understand? Use this to make your question more specific.

Comment: Thanks Kerrek,
but the example in the document about virtual Inheritance there is no virtual methods, therefor, there is no virtual tables for those methods there is just a pointer which points to the Base class. I need to know what happens if such methods exist.

Comment: @user2811205 Please do not make changes to people's source code in questions!

Answer (score 0):

i think there will be two vtable (i.e. for each object), because each object starts in different location .